# How to parse 5 Arrays in one object using JSON

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm stuck at this problem, The output of the JSOn is

```
"forecast":[ 
{"day":"Today","condition":"MostlyClear","high_temperature":"94","low_temperature":"70"},
{"day":"Tomorrow","condition":"Sunny","high_temperature":"95","low_temperature":"69"},
{"day":"Saturday","condition":"Sunny","high_temperature":"94","low_temperature":"71"},
{"day":"Sunday","condition":"Sunny","high_temperature":"93","low_temperature":"70"},
{"day":"Monday","condition":"Sunny","high_temperature":"94","low_temperature":"70"}
]
```

I need condition key to show the values in the tableview cell. And my code is

```
temp=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[dataLoader httpData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Patient Details %@",temp);

array = [[temp JSONValue] objectForKey:@"forecast"];

NSDictionary* dic = [array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSString *strDay = [dic objectForKey:@"day"];
NSString *stringCondition = [dic objectForKey:@"condition"];
NSLog(@"condition is %@", stringCondition);
NSString *stringTemp = [dic objectForKey:@"high_temperature"];
NSString *stringLow = [dic objectForKey:@"low_temperature"];
```

But it is showing only one condition value, i want all the five conditions at a time. I also tried to use `NSArray` instead of `NSString` for condtion with no luck.

Comment: Does it show only 1 row? As you are using "indexPath row" I assume that this runs in cellForRowAtIndexPath of some UITableViewController. If so, what do you return as number of rows in section 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 array = [[temp JSONValue] objectForKey:@"forecast"];
```

Make a for loop in this place :

```
for(NSUInteger index = 0; index<[array count]; index++)
{

 NSDictionary* dic = [array objectAtIndex:index];
 NSString *strDay = [dic objectForKey:@"day"];
 NSString *stringCondition = [dic objectForKey:@"condition"];
 NSLog(@"condition is %@", stringCondition);
 NSString *stringTemp = [dic objectForKey:@"high_temperature"];
 NSString *stringLow = [dic objectForKey:@"low_temperature"];
}
```

Hope this will help...